# parsing xml in android. i don't know what's wrong

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, file

```
try{
    File myDir = new File("c:/AndExam2/TestList/res/Xml");   
    File file = new File(myDir,"database.xml");        
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuildFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuild = docBuildFact.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuild.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
}
```

i don't know what's wrong. this code always makes

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /c:/AndExam2/TestList/res/Xml/database.xml : open failed:ENOENT(no such file or directory)
```

Comment: are you trying to run this code in `Android` device?

Comment: copy xml file in asset folder..

Comment: What a great try to access the file from the computer !!!!.. Are you sure you can access the file from computer like this ?

Comment: no i was never try this

Answer (score 0):

you must put the xml file to sdcard,and read it from sdcard ,not the computer hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
File myDir = new File("c:/AndExam2/TestList/res/Xml");
```

you should put file in asset folder or row folder or in sdcard

in raw

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxmlfile);
```

[see this example may this useful](http://www.androidpeople.com/xml-parsing)